# How to detect the lock button action?

Tags: ios, swift, background-task, uibackgroundtask, swift5

How to detect the lock button action when the application is on background mode.So that when ever the user unlock the phone i want the open my application in foreground.

Please help ..

Comment: I think that method is not possible. if your app is in backgound you need to manually enter it into foreground. you cannot do that by code

Comment: @vishnuanilkumar  Thank you , i was trying to make a custom lock for the phone  by sign to  lock with the email id. is it possible ?

Comment: No, you can't modify the behaviour of iOS in that way.